# F# ((*)2) and ((<<<)1) act differently

Tags: f#, functional-programming, mapping, bitwise-operators

I have these two pieces of code:

- `[| 0 .. N-1 |] |> Array.map((<<<)1)`
- `[| 0 .. N-1 |] |> Array.map((*)2)`

I thought they do absolutely the same things but they don't.
In first case I get `1, 2, 4` and in second - `0, 2, 4`. I don't understand why there is `1` in the first case? If I write `let a = 0 <<< 1`, I get `0`. Is this a bug?
Thanks!

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The arguments are not in the order you think, they are the other way around.

Compare it with:

```
let a = 1 <<< 0 // this is equivalent to ((<<<)1) 0
```

The first argument after the parenthesized operator is the left argument, not the right.